# Is every router is a switch?

Tags: router, cisco, switching, aruba

I wanna know this hierarchy.Does any router can do what switch do?

My master said it "yes,router is switch at the same time." Is that real? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, we are not google.

Comment: I know you are not.I'm asking it to helpful people,not to you.Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No".
Ports could be switched from L3 to L2 back and forth to serve routing or switching functions, but this is not general rule. Depending of vendor and model there could be no option for port level switching. There also could be no advansed switching features on router